# How delete all files from their folders that not listed in csv file

Tags: python, csv

How i can remove all vedios files from folders that not listed in csv file
where i have base folder contins sub folders each of them incude some of vedios files , and csv file include vedio path (sub folder/vedios file)

so how i can change this script to deal with my issue

```
import os
import pandas as pd

path = "/Users/shaimaa/Downloads/Code/audio-visual-dataset-master/results_news/news/"

flist = pd.read_csv('/Users/shaimaa/Downloads/Code/audio-visual-dataset-master/results_news/news/Csv files/A_V_dataset.csv')

file_name = flist['fileName'].tolist()

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    print(filename)
    if filename == file_name:
        continue
    elif filename != file_name:
        os.remove(filename)
```

---

PermissionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
15         #Get full path of file and remove it
16         full_file_path = os.path.join(path, filename)
---> 17         os.remove(full_file_path)

PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/Users/shaimaa/Downloads/Code/audio-visual-dataset-master/results_news/news/Politics_news_24_p2'

then i have this error

`file_name`

['Politics_news_3_p1/289.mp4',
'Politics_news_3_p1/262.mp4',
'Politics_news_3_p1/276.mp4',
'Politics_news_3_p1/15.mp4',
'Politics_news_3_p1/470.mp4',
'Politics_news_3_p1/302.mp4',
'Politics_news_3_p1/465.mp4',
'Politics_news_3_p1/317.mp4',
'Politics_news_3_p1/115.mp4',
'Politics_news_3_p1/288.mp4',
'Politics_news_3_p1/275.mp4',
'Politics_news_3_p1/467.mp4',
....

Comment: By default, most applications can't access your Downloads folder on macOS.  You'll need to grant the appropriate permissions to Python, or move your files to a different location, or use a different operating system.

Answer (score 0):

Is that what I'm getting from your code logic?

The file that you need to delete is not included in this csv file, right?

```py
import os

import pandas as pd

path = "/Users/shaimaa/Downloads/Code/audio-visual-dataset-master/results_news/news/"

flist = pd.read_csv(
    '/Users/shaimaa/Downloads/Code/audio-visual-dataset-master/results_news/news/Csv files/A_V_dataset.csv'
)

file_name = flist['fileName'].tolist()

file_name_set = set(file_name)


def remove_video(dir_path):
    if not dir_path:
        return
    for filename in os.listdir(dir_path):
        print(filename)
        file_path = os.path.join(path, filename)
        if os.path.isdir(file_path):
            remove_video(file_path)
        if filename in file_name_set:
            continue
        if os.path.exists(file_path):
            os.remove(filename)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    remove_video(path)
```

Comment: I had an error when using your code [Errno 1] Operation not permitted:Politics_news_24_p2

Comment: Politics_news_24_p2 is folder have number of vedio files

Comment: @Shema  You mean you need to recursively delete it?

If subdirectories exist in the current directory, perform the same traversal and delete files

Comment: @Shema   I updated the recursively deleted code,

But make sure your current user has permission to delete。